# Eigenstates of $L^2$ and $L_z$ no $r$ dependence Why?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, wavefunction, coordinate-systems, spherical-harmonics

Does anybody know why the eigenstates common to the casimir operator $L^2$ and the $z$-axis angular momentum $L_z$ have no $r$ dependence (they are written $\psi_{m,l} (\theta, \phi)$)?

Is it because $L^2$ and $L_z$ only depend on $\theta$ and $\phi$? I have the feeling it is because of this, but I cannot convince myself.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/683779/. But I still don't really understand..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Arguments of the eigenfunctions of angular momentum](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/594070/)